# R merge or lookup cell value based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two tables, and I want to transfer information from one of them into the other.

There are names and subnames. Each name + subname combination has a value associated with it, which is calculated independently in the first step.

In the next step, each name is assigned two special subnames (sub1 and sub2), and I need to retrieve the value associated with each name + subname pair.

In other words, for each name I need to retrieve the value for name+sub1 and the value for name+sub2.

In the first table, each row has a name, and a value for every possible sub-name. Here the subnames are called `x`, `y`, `w`, and `z`. The values are numbers.

```
Name    x    y    w    z
abc     4    8    3    1
def     2    5    1    7
```

In the second table, each row has a name in the first column and two relevant sub-names in the next two columns. Both tables have the full set of names in the first column, but not every subname in the second table exists in the first table. For these rows, it would be fine just to return 'NA.'

```
Name    Sub1        Sub2
abc     x           y
def     w           z
```

I want to combine these tables so I get something like this:

```
Name    Sub1        Sub2    Sub1.Value    Sub2.Value
abc     x           y       4             8
def     w           z       1             7
```

These are copy/pasteable sample tables (the first table actually has ~1k rows and ~30k columns).

```
first.table=data.frame(Name=c('abc','def'),x=c(4,2),y=c(8,5),w=c(3,1),z=c(1,7))
second.table=data.frame(Name=c('abc','def'),Sub1=c('x','w'),Sub2=c('y','z'))
```

Comment: Have you looked into merge() and match()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Et voilà:

```
library(reshape2)
# melt into long format
ldf <- melt(first.table,id.vars='Name')

# merge on Name and the Sub's
second.table <- merge(second.table,ldf,by.x=c('Name','Sub1'),by.y=c('Name','variable'))
second.table <- merge(second.table,ldf,by.x=c('Name','Sub2'),by.y=c('Name','variable'))

# rename columns to the correct values
colnames(second.table)[4:5] <- c('Sub1.Value','Sub2.Value')
```